# conemu - start multiple commands in new window

Tags: conemu

I have the following **run.cmd** file. This runs 2 scripts (a webserver and a watch script) and opens a new console. All good.

How can I run all these scripts to be opened in a "new window" conemu interface?
For example: if I run this ***run.cmd 3 times, I should have 3 conemu windows with 3 tabs each***

```
//how to open first a "new conemu" window here? and then run the scripts in this new window?
start server.run.cmd -new_console:s
start watch.cmd -new_console:s
start cmd -new_console
```

Answer (score 0):

You should run `ConEmu64.exe -NoSingle`.

https://conemu.github.io/en/ConEmuArgs.html

For example, you may do something like

```
if "%~1" == "-new_window" goto do_run
start ConEmu64.exe -NoSingle -run "%~0" -new_window
goto :EOF
:do_run
ConEmuC /async /c server.run.cmd
cmd /c watch.cmd -new_console:s
cmd /c cmd -new_console
```